# Hyperledger fabric : Balance Transfer : Getting error while executing ./runApp.sh

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

While running `./runApp.sh` command as shown in the hyperledger fabric-samples found [here](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-samples/blob/release-1.4/balance-transfer), I am getting the following error after installing the node modules.

> ```
> Error: ============== node modules installed already =============   
> /home/user/fabric/fabric-samples/balance-transfer/app.js:110   
> app.post('/users', async function(req, res) { ^^^^^ SyntaxError:   
> missing ) after argument list at Object.exports.runInThisContext
> (vm.js:76:16) at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
> ```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the node_modules folder and try to reinstall once.
In the fabric samples docs,follow 2nd option steps:
Removing node_modules folder:

### $ rm -rf node_modules

Steps to bring from "2nd Option steps"
Terminal Window 1

$ cd fabric-samples/balance-transfer

./runApp.sh
Open localhost:3000

after this open one more terminal
Terminal Window 2
check whether jq installed?
./testAPIs.sh -l golang,
from this you will get:
POST request Create channel  ...

{"success":true,"message":"Channel 'mychannel' created Successfully"}

POST request Join channel on Org1

{"success":true,"message":"Successfully joined peers in organization Org1 to the channel:mychannel"}

POST request Join channel on Org2

{"success":true,"message":"Successfully joined peers in organization Org2 to the channel:mychannel"}

POST request Update anchor peers on Org1